# Module with libraries

Tags: android, gradle

My app is splitted into a few modules.
E.g.
Modules A has implementation RxJava
Modules B has implementation RxJava

Each module has implementation in build.gradle RxJava

Is it possible to create something like Module C and implement only there RxJava and then Module A and B just extend module C ?
I would like to have only 1 place where I implement e.g. RxJava

Comment: afaik, you cannot really do that

Comment: if no, it is strange

Comment: for example, if we use Library A which uses Library B, we dont have to add these libraries from B to our project, how authors of library A achieve that ?

Comment: yea, but you are now talking about libraries, it is possible to create a class which implements / extends intefaces / classes from a different library, this isn't the case for modules

Comment: Modules are libraries, so wrapping a library in a module would still leave you with another library. What is the root problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, Module C could have `api` (instead of `implementation`) for its RxJava dependency. Then Module A and Module B could depend on Module C and pick up RxJava via transitive dependencies.